# pandas transpose specific columns to rows keep custom attributes

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, transpose

I loaded an excel file in a dataframe which contains questions, answers and some custom attributes in the first three columns. I would like to transpose all the answers to rows but keep the first columns with attributes by every answer.

Input:

| ID | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | question_1 | question_2 | question_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | monday | mix1 | answer_1 | answer_2 | answer_3 |
| 2 | friday | mix2 | answer_1 | answer_2 | answer_3 |

Output:

| ID | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | monday | mix1 | question_1 | answer_1 |
| 1 | monday | mix1 | question_2 | answer_2 |
| 1 | monday | mix1 | question_3 | answer_3 |
| 2 | friday | mix2 | question_1 | answer_1 |
| 2 | friday | mix2 | question_2 | answer_2 |
| 2 | friday | mix2 | question_3 | answer_3 |

I looked at df.transpose, but that won't exclude / multiply the attribute columns.

Anyone an idea? TIA

ABBOV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `melt`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
 'attribute_1': ['monday', 'friday'],
 'attribute_2': ['mix1', 'mix2'],
 'question_1': ['answer_1', 'answer_1'],
 'question_2': ['answer_2', 'answer_2'],
 'question_3': ['answer_3', 'answer_3']})

df = df.melt(id_vars=['ID','attribute_1','attribute_2'],
             var_name='question',
             value_name='answer').sort_values(by='ID')

print(df)
```

Output

```
   ID attribute_1 attribute_2    question    answer
0   1      monday        mix1  question_1  answer_1
2   1      monday        mix1  question_2  answer_2
4   1      monday        mix1  question_3  answer_3
1   2      friday        mix2  question_1  answer_1
3   2      friday        mix2  question_2  answer_2
5   2      friday        mix2  question_3  answer_3
```